# Angular: CORS preflight response did not succeed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

Good day everyone,

I'm having an issue with my users registration app and I hope you guys can help me figured out what's going on:

I'm using MongoDb, Express, Angular and NodeJs and this is how it looks in app.js (I'm including also the screenshot of the error that shows both in Firefox and Chrome). Thank you in advance

[image]

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app =express();
var user_routes = require('./routes/user');
var follow_routes = require('./routes/follow');
var publication_routes = require('./routes/publication');
var message_routes = require('./routes/message');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
next();

}); 

app.use('/api', user_routes);
app.use('/api', follow_routes);
app.use('/api', publication_routes);
app.use('/api', message_routes);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

Comment: Thanks so much! these var declaration plus installing the npm cors package solved the problem.. :)

Comment: there are several cors questions everyday on SO, you should really learn to use search engine, before posting such questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use npm cors package to white list url or allow any origin request.

Answer (score 0):

You should Add CORS headers - see https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html